# How to choose javascript as a preferred language for writing business login in Oracle MAF

Tags: oracle-maf

In the feature list, oracle have mentioned the user can choose the preferred language either Java or JavaScript for writing business logic.

If it's true, how can i choose.

Answer (score 1):

MAF supports content being presented in three forms: AMX components, Custom HTML + JavaScript and External Web pages. AMX is the preferred mechanism. But, you can create custom HTML/JS pages as well.
See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf230/mobile/develop-maf/GUID-6F391DA6-3D6F-4823-A732-28851AC9DCAF.htm#ADFMF25104).
When you create the content for a Feature in MAF, you select the type of content that you want. Note: Taskflow Navigation is available only for AMX pages. With Custom HTML./JS you have to handle all navigation between pages yourself.

If you choose AMX pages you can easily navigate between pages using task flows and call Java code when events occur like button clicks, etc. it is *strongly* recommended to use AMX and Java for MAF. One uses JS *only* if their requirements cannot be met with AMX and Java which is not typical.

Comment: Is there any samples to navigate between local HTML pages using JavaScript in the oracle MAf.

Also is there any link available for writing business logic using JavaScript in Oracle MAF.

Comment: You should check out the docs http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf230/mobile/develop-maf/GUID-6F391DA6-3D6F-4823-A732-28851AC9DCAF.htm#ADFMF265   &  the oracle channel for MAF on youtube.  Note that JS is not the preferred content type because it does not support navigation in task flows like AMX pages do and the developer is completely responsible for their own JS - It is *strongly* suggested you use AMX pages and custom Java for business logic or MAF.